# PouchDB 5.3.0 - Error: Database location or iosDatabaseLocation value is now mandatory in openDatabase call

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, pouchdb

Having issues with **PouchDB 5.3.0**. I am getting following error in my Ionic app

> Error: Database location or iosDatabaseLocation value is now mandatory
> in openDatabase call

The above error is because of below line of code:

```
> var websql = new PouchDB('websqlpouch', {adapter: 'websql'});
```

I am trying to use **SQLite plugin** in Ionic app.

Answer (score 14):

The problem is already reported: https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/4979
You need to wait for a new version or use an older plugin version of sqlite-storage:

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-sqlite-storage
cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage@0.7.14
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Comment: Thanks hypery2k you saved me from a headache.

Comment: you're welcome. Seem to be that the PouchDB team will fix this issue soon ;)

Comment: We added better defenses against SQLite Storage Plugin introducing breaking changes in PouchDB 5.3.2, but you still need to add the `location` parameter when you create a PouchDB. To avoid this, you can also install an alternative SQLite Plugin I wrote: https://github.com/nolanlawson/cordova-plugin-sqlite-2

Answer (score 8):

Seems [the issue](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/3617) was closed a year back.

I am on version `5.3.1` and I went ahead and used the `location` key and it works:

```
var db = new PouchDB('myDB', {adapter: 'websql', location:'default'});
```

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage), using the `default` value for the `location` key.

PouchDB: Version 5.3.1

Cordova-sqlite-storage: Version 1.2.0

Comment: I got this same error - and got it fixed with this same solution - on an Android device.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/litehelpers/cordova-sqlite-ext You can get the new plugin version of sqlite-storage in this link.

Comment: you can use this plugin via  
`cordova plugin rm cordova-sqlite-storage  && cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-ext  
`